# How do I get both values for two html.editorfor dates to make the both accessible in the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in my cshtml page:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <label asp-for="StartDate"></label><br />
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
        }
    </div>
    </div>   
    <br />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <label asp-for="EndDate"></label><br />
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

The StartDate is accessible in the controller but the Enddate is null.  If I swap the order, the EndDate is good and the StartDate is null. So, it appears that the way I am doing it, only the first value is passed.  How can I get both values?

This is the model definition:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date Only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "To Date")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date Only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "From Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

I'm sure this is something simple but I can't figure it out.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was right, it was simple. I needed to have both dates in the same Html.BeginForm().

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <label asp-for="StartDate"></label><br />
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
                <br />
                <label asp-for="EndDate"></label><br />
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```